# My codeigniter is using another database instead the database from database.php

Tags: database, codeigniter

I have two copies of my project, i've changed the database's name, but 
even though I changed the database name in the database.php, the two projects are using the same database!!
The projects are in the same server.

One of this server the conection is like this:

```
$db['sas'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'MyServerIp',
'username' => 'sastest',
'password' => '************',
'database' => 'sasClone',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => TRUE,
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => FALSE);
```

The other is like this:

```
$db['sas'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'MyServerIp',
'username' => 'sas',
'password' => '******',
'database' => 'sas',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => TRUE,
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => FALSE);
```

and in the application i use the database like this:

```
$dbsas = $this->load->database("sas", TRUE);
```

I hope i was clear, i cannot understand why they are using the same database if the database.php is different, thank u.

Comment: you are defining the array `$db['sas']` twice, so only the latter counts

Comment: Actually, they are not from the same system, one system is a copy of other, this conection are from two different database.php

Comment: It happens because you probably forgot to change the ´$application_folder´ value in the ´index.php´ file on the new copy of the application.